# Slow inserts, application stress test, by direct procedures. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, architecture

I'm no expert in mysql.
But what i'm trying to do is inserting large number of records to my database, to stress test my application.
I'm doing this by seeding random data to my tables;
Here is my code snippet to do so using procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 237692004 DO
        INSERT INTO ok (field) VALUES (field);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

The problem here, is it takes about 5 seconds to insert just 100 rows???
And that is too much time...
My question is how to reduce that time???
To use my total memory power???
What am I missing here?

Comment: where the value of field comes from?

Comment: Why are you saying "*100 rows*"?

Comment: Just random data, lets assume it's one field, not indexed nor primary. and set @field = `randomString`, That's not the problem, the problem is it's too slow???

Comment: select count(*) from ok while the loop is executed, and you will take a glimpse of the performance :) @ErayBalkanli

Comment: Does your 'ok' table have many columns?

Comment: @Neels Only one field for testing purposes only, I'm using ubuntu, on a powerful computer. 128 GB available ram! :D 
The problem is not the computer power, the problem is my own ignorance about sql servers.
That's why I'm looking for a way to do this faster than 100 rows per 5 seconds.
What am I trying to accomplish here is making everything easier for me as a developer.

Comment: What db engine? Also if you are providing code then paste the actual code you are using. Not another version of it.

Comment: @krishKM
I tried show engines; in mysql command line.
And it looks like I'm using innoDB.
I don't know much about engines and drivers, as I said not an expert.

    MyISAM             | YES  <br/>     
    MRG_MYISAM         | YES  <br/>     
    CSV                | YES  <br/>
    BLACKHOLE          | YES  <br/>
    PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES  <br/>     
    InnoDB             | DEFAULT  <br/>
    ARCHIVE            | YES  <br/>
    MEMORY            | YES  <br/>
    FEDERATED          | NO`  <br/> 

For the code, trust me this is the actual code, I have nothing to hide. :D

Comment: Your code above should not work. Change the insert command to. "Insert into `ok`(`field`) values(i);" and see whether each loop round is inserted.

Comment: @krishKM That's not my question sir,
my question is about performance. It's slow inserting records, the loop should be executed faster than that!!!

Comment: Your loop isn't inserting any record. At least with that code above. It shouldn't..

Comment: @krishKM I have no problem writing the code. even after updating the `field` to a string or an integer. It's slow.
The loop is working when I select count(*) from the table.
Please read my post carefully. I'm asking about server performance, not code error.